# Find probability distribution of stopping time consisting of a two-sided barrior and a time constrained for Brownian motion with drift?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stopping-times, stochastic-differential-equations

For the following Brownian motion with drift $X_t = X_0 + \mu t + \sigma B_t$ where $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$, $ \sigma > 0$ and $X_0 \in (a,b)$ which is a solution to the stochastic differential equation:
\begin{align*}
dX_t = \mu dt + \sigma dB_t \ .
\end{align*}
We define the stopping time:
\begin{align*}
\gamma = \min\{\tau,T\}
\end{align*}
Where $\tau = \inf\{t: X_t \notin (a,b)\}$ and $T>0$ is a constant. There is three ways this process can be stopped: If $X_t$ hits the upper or the lower barrior, that is $X_t = b$ or $X_t = a$, or the process will be stopped by the time constrained t = T. I want to find these three probabilities $P(X_\gamma = a)$, $P(X_\gamma = b)$ and $P(a < X_\gamma < b)$ does anyone have a strategy to solve this problem?

I can solve the problem in the case where $T = \infty$, such that we only have $\gamma = \tau = \inf\{t: X_t \notin (a,b)\}$ by using Dynkin's formula, but I cannot see if it is possible to solve the problem using a similar approach?

Here is my solution to the simplified problem ($T=\infty$) :

We define a reward function $c:\{a,b\} \to \mathbb{R}$, such that $c(a) = 0$ and $c(b) = 1$. Now given that the process starts at $x$, that is $X_0 = x$, the expectation of the reward function at $X_{\tau}$, must be equal to the probability that $X_{\tau}$ equals $b$ thus:
\begin{align*}
    \textbf{E}^x c(X_{\tau}) = c(a)\textbf{P}^x\{X_{\tau} = a \} + c(b)\textbf{P}^x\{X_{\tau} = b \} 
    = \textbf{P}^x\{X_{\tau} = b \}
\end{align*}
By Dynkin's formula we have:
\begin{align*}
    \textbf{E}^x h(X_{\tau}) = h(x) + \textbf{E}^x \int_0^\tau (Lh)(X_{t}) dt \ .
\end{align*}
Where $L$ is the forward Kolmogorov operator:
\begin{align*}
    (Lh)(x) = \mu \partial_x h(x) + \frac{\sigma^2}{2} \partial_x^2 h(x) \ .
\end{align*}
We see that if we solve the Dirichlet problem:
\begin{align*}
    \begin{cases}
    (Lh)(x) = 0 \ , \ x \in (a,b) \ , \\
    h(x) = c(x) \ , \ x \in \{a,b\} \ .
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
Then by Dynkin's formular we get:
\begin{align*}
    \textbf{E}^x h(X_{\tau}) = h(x) + \textbf{E}^x \int_0^\tau (Lh)(X_{t}) dt = h(x)
\end{align*}
and since $h(X_{\tau}) = c(X_{\tau})$ we have:
\begin{align*}
    h(x) = \textbf{E}^x h(X_{\tau}) = \textbf{E}^x c(X_{\tau}) =  \textbf{P}^x\{X_{\tau} = b \} \ .
\end{align*}
In words the solution $h(x)$ to the Dirichlet problem is the probability that the process $X_{\tau}$ at time $\tau$ equals $b$ when the process starts at $x$.

We will now solve the Dirichlet problem. We have the following differential equation we have to solve:
\begin{align*}
    D \partial_x^2 h + \mu \partial_x h = 0 \ .
\end{align*}
We define $k = \mu/D$ such that we have:
\begin{align*}
    \partial_x^2 h + k \partial_x h = 0 \ .
\end{align*}
By multiplication by $\exp(kx)$ we see that:
\begin{align*}
    (\partial_x^2 h) \exp(kx) + (\partial_x h) k \exp(kx) = 0
\end{align*}
Then we have:
\begin{align*}
    \partial_x ((\partial_x h) \exp(kx)) = 0 \ .
\end{align*}
We integrate both sides:
\begin{align*}
    (\partial_x h) \exp(kx) =  - C_1 \ .
\end{align*}
By multiplication of $\exp(-kx)$ and integration we get:
\begin{align*}
    h(x) - C_2 = -\int C_1 \exp(-kx) dx = \frac{C_1}{k} \exp(-kx) \ .
\end{align*}
The final solution is therefore:
\begin{align*}
    h(x) = \frac{C_1}{k} \exp(-kx) + C_2 \ .
\end{align*}
By the boundary conditions we have:
\begin{align*}
    h(a) = \frac{C_1}{k} \exp(-ka) + C_2 = 0 \ ,
\end{align*}
thus
\begin{align*}
    C_2 = - \frac{C_1}{k} \exp(-ka) \ .
\end{align*}
For $x = b$ we get:
\begin{align*}
    h(b) = \frac{C_1}{k} \exp(-kb) - \frac{C_1}{k} \exp(-ka) = 1 \ ,
\end{align*}
then we have:
\begin{align*}
    C_1 = \frac{k}{\exp(-kb) - \exp(-ka)} \ .
\end{align*}
The solution is therefore:
\begin{align*}
    h(x) = \frac{\exp(-ka) - \exp(-kx)}{\exp(-ka) - \exp(-kb)} \ .
\end{align*}
Now by replacing $h(x)$ with $ \textbf{P}^x\{X_{\tau} = b \} $ and $k$ with $2\mu/\sigma^2$ we have:
\begin{align*}
    \textbf{P}^x\{X_{\tau} = b \} = \frac{\exp(\frac{-2\mu a}{\sigma^2}) - \exp(\frac{-2\mu x}{\sigma^2})}{\exp(\frac{-2\mu a}{\sigma^2}) - \exp(\frac{-2\mu b}{\sigma^2})} = \frac{1 - \exp(\frac{-2\mu}{\sigma^2}(x-a))}{1 - \exp(\frac{-2\mu }{\sigma^2}(b-a))} \ .
\end{align*}
And then $\textbf{P}^x\{X_{\tau} = a \} = 1 - \textbf{P}^x\{X_{\tau} = b \}$.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the notorious [Handbook](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-0348-7652-0), esp. Ch. 2 'Brownian motion with drift', 2.3 'First exit time'.